# php mysql query for 3 tables (users, topics, messages)

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need to list results topics with selected user and with messages IDs like this:

> test 1 (topic)
>
> message id (i will add a link for this ID)

(may multiple records with same user for same topics in messages table)

```
-------------------------------------
TABLES
-------------------------------------
TABLE:    users
id        int  (auto_increment)
user      varchar
-------------------------------------
TABLE:    topics
id        int
user_id   int  (index)
topic     varcahar
-------------------------------------
TABLE:    messages 
id        int  (auto_increment)
user_id   int  (index)
topic_id  int  (index)
message   text
-------------------------------------
```

I did try this code but I am getting errors.

```
SELECT users.id,users.user,topics.topic,messages.id FROM users,topics,messages WHERE messages.user_id=users.id and users.user='$_GET[user]' ORDER BY topics.topic
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Firstly, when you say "but I am getting errors" and fail to share exactly what errors you are getting, you kill a small part of the soul of everyone who reads that.  Secondly, you probably want to use some JOINs to link one table to the next via foreign keys to get at the data you wish to extract.

Comment: share the code , difficult to tell the exact error from these code of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, u.user, t.topic, m.id
FROM topics t
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.user = 'xyz'
ORDER BY t.topic
```

But you should escape `$_GET[user]`

Comment: a lot of thanks for your answer. query is worked. but if records more than 1000 amounts, result coming very late. what can I do for this? I have INDEX for user_id and topic_id

Comment: Use index for every id. And if you dont need all rows than you can use `LIMIT x OFSET y`